# Formatting output of Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet)

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a DataTable. When it's serialized into JSON with

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable)
```

I get results in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "CLICK_KEY": 6254523744,
        "WEB_SERVER_KEY": 291,
        "PREV_CLICK_KEY": 0,
        "NEXT_CLICK_KEY": 0,
        "SESSION_KEY": 214981151,
        *more key value pairs*
    },
    {
        "CLICK_KEY": 6254523745,
        "WEB_SERVER_KEY": 291,
        "PREV_CLICK_KEY": 0,
        "NEXT_CLICK_KEY": 0,
        "SESSION_KEY": 214746780
        *more key value pairs*
    },
    *many more objects (for each row)*
]
```

Since I have many columns and many rows, the resulting JSON is huge.  This is mostly because column names are long and keep repeating for each row of data.

Is there a way to change settings of Json.Net so that the resulting JSON string is reduced in size? For instance, by formatting output as:

```
{
    "NAMES": [
        "CLICK_KEY",
        "WEB_SERVER_KEY",
        "PREV_CLICK_KEY",
        "NEXT_CLICK_KEY",
        "SESSION_KEY",
        *more keys*
    ],
    "VALUES": [
        [6254523744, 291, 0, 0, 214981151, *more values*],
        [6254523745, 291, 0, 0, 214746780, *more values*],
        *many more arrays of values (for each row)*
    ]
}
```

I will not need to deserialize this back into a table or another object, so a "one-way" solution would work.

Thanks!

**Update:**
I followed advice from @spender & @TravisJ and transformed my `DataTable` into another type for which Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject() outputs what I need. Note how I start at `DataSet` level so if it contains more than one `DataTable`, it will include each one in the array.

```
var converted = from x in dataSet.Tables.Cast<DataTable>()
                select new
                {
                  NAMES = x.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(l => l.Caption),
                  VALUES = x.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(l => l.ItemArray)
                };
string jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(converted);
```

Comment: Why do you want to format? You use JSON to transfer the data not present it.

Comment: @Ash - Please read the question. I need to reduce the size of resulting JSON object.

Comment: Why not transform your data to that shape before serialization? Looks like an object with an `IEnumerable<string>` and an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>`? Similarly, you could unpack it at the other end.

Comment: I think you need to start from the beginning with what you are trying to do. Why serialize something you don't want to serialize back?

Comment: That is a very good question, @AshBurlaczenko!

Comment: @spender - I could certainly write extra code to separately extract column names and rows of values out of my `DataTable`, but was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @Ash - I don't need to deserialize because I simply need to consume this JSON in JavaScript.

Comment: Who cares how long your json is? The output of json.NET's serialize method is based on the format of it's input. The only way to change the format of your output is to change the input. With a large data set it will be an expensive operation. And worse, it's a needless one that will create the need for an accompanying expensive and useless operation. All to shorten the length of a string...

Comment: I see a considerable down-the-wire size reduction in OP's scheme, but also considerable obfuscation. Why not switch on gzip compression and forget about it?

Answer (score 1):

You could just convert the datatable to the format you need using a linq projection:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
 dataTable.Select(
  d => new {
   Names = d.Columns.Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToArray(),
   Values = d.Rows.Select(r => r.ToArray()).ToArray()
  })
);
```

Comment: The code above didn't work as is, but after slight modification I got it to work. Thanks!