# MVC JsonConvert.SerializeObject - how to get Column and Data Row Arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on serializing a viewmodel with MVC5 with JsonConvert.SerializeObject and the result is coming up with is an array for each record (e.g. [{PropertyName: Value,...},{PropertyName: Value,...}]. I am trying to fill a slick grid to get the property names dynamically and I have seen others have arrays that have the Property names in one array and then the data rows in another. How can I create [{Column Names},{DataRowValues}] so i can get the property names from this array. I will be deserializing this data as well. I was using this link as a reference, but I am using a List and had trouble making it work [Formatting output of Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659560/formatting-output-of-newtonsoft-json-jsonconvert-serializeobjectdataset). Thanks.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GeneratePlans()
    {
        //code here to create and populate view model

        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(viewModel, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: What does the viewmodel look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server, if you need dynamic property resolution, you can use reflection to enumerate the properties and values of your view model.

Since you wish to have your JSON split into an array for property names and an array for property values, we need a class to hold that result.  I've left this class deliberately simple since it will just be used for holding values for JSON serialization.

```
class ObjectPropertyNamesAndValues
{
     public List<string> Names { get; set; }
     public List<object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a function that will populate an instance of `ObjectPropertyNamesAndValues` given a `viewModel` instance of any type.

```
ObjectPropertyNamesAndValues GetObjectPropertyNamesAndValues(object viewModel) 
{
    if (viewModel == null)
        return null;

    var result = new JsonObjectPropertyValues();
    result.Names = new List<string>();
    result.Values = new List<object>();

    var propertyInfo = viewModel.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (var property in propertyInfo)
    {
        if (!propertyInfo.CanRead)
            continue;

        // you can add other checks here, too, such as whether or not
        // the property has a certain custom attribute or not

        result.Names.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
        result.Values.Add(property.GetValue(viewModel));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now you can implement your function like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GeneratePlans()
{
    //code here to create and populate view model

    // get the object properties and values for transport as JSON
    Debug.Assert(viewModel != null);
    var objectPropertyNamesAndValues = GetObjectPropertyNamesAndValues(viewModel);

    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectPropertyNamesAndValues, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: thanks I will try this out and let you know who it goes